# showSaveDialog appears behind main FXML

Tags: fxml, savefiledialog

I have used showSaveDialog in a controller class for an FXML. When a hyperlink is clicked, the showSaveDialog should open a dialog box to save a file. The dialog box to Save file opens up, but it appears behind the fxml from which it is called.
 I have to minimize the main fxml and then save the file using the showsavedialog window. Please help

```
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setSelectedFile(new File(fileName));
    fc.setDialogTitle("Choose a path to Save file");
    int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(this);
```

Comment: Why are you using JFileChooser instead of javafx.stage.FileChooser in the JavaFX application?

Comment: If i use Filechoser I get the following error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Folder parameter must be a valid folder.. For the line: File file1 = fcr.showSaveDialog(stage);.

Comment: "IAE: Folder parameter must be a valid folder" means that you are configuring FileChooser.setInitialDirectory() with a File argument which either does not exists or is not a directory. You will have to either create the target directory beforehand.

Comment: And do not forget to pass a valid Window reference (for example, your primary stage) as an argument to FileChooser.showOpenDialog() or FileChooser.showSaveDialog() - this is the required step if you want the FileChooser to be modal with respect to your main window.

Comment: ya FileChooser.setInitialDirectory()  worked :) Thank you. But how can i set the selectedfile to save in location selected by the user? It is like saving a file from one loaction(which will be constant) to other(where user wants to save it).. With JFileChooser i used setSelectedFile.

Comment: I couldnt find setInitialFileName in FileChooser..

Comment: FileChooser.setInitialFileName() method and related initialFileNameProperty appeared in JavaFX 2.2.40. Make sure you are using the latest JDK 7.

Comment: I am using Netbeans 7.4 , javafx.runtime.version=2.2.25, and jdk 7. When i try using FileChooser.setInitialFileName() it says method not found. there is only setInitialDirectory and setTitle available in FileChooser for me.